# Azure CDN from Verizon Premium HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: redirects, https, cdn, azure

I have created an Azure CDN endpoint (like `example.azureedge.net`) using Verizon Premium Pricing Tier.

I want to create a rule to redirect to the HTTPS protocol (like `https://example.azureedge.net`) whenever a user uses the HTTP protocol (like `http://example.azureedge.net`).

How can I achieve this using the rules engine of Azure CDN from Verizon Premium?

Comment: Do you have access to a .htaccess file? If so https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376219/htaccess-redirect-http-to-https

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for quick reply. I don't have access to htaccess file

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887411/redirect-from-http-to-https-in-azure-cdn-standard-verizon

Comment: and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193825/enforce-http-to-https-in-azure-premium-verizon-cdn

Comment: and finally https://medium.com/azure-architects/configuring-azure-cdn-http-https-redirection-2a9e4aab0a77

Comment: All found with a Duck Duck Go search ;o)

Comment: Hi Steve, the StackOverflow answer also points to the same medium article. In the medium article, the source for the rule is/80CAAt2/mywebapp/(.*), I have already tried using this value as the source, but Verizon gives the error that the source does not match the source any existing origin for the account. Can you please suggest what value, should I use for the source

Answer (score 1):

The [Medium article that Steve linked](https://medium.com/azure-architects/configuring-azure-cdn-http-https-redirection-2a9e4aab0a77) seems to have the answer. To quote the main steps:

> 1. From the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), Select the CDN profile
> 2. Click on **Manage** to open the configuration page
> 3. From the **HTTP Large** menu, select **Rules Engine**
> 4. Update the Name / Description i.e. **HTTP to HTTPS redirect**
> 5. Change the **Always** dropdown menu to **Request Scheme**
> 6. Click the **Features+** button and select **URL Redirect**
> 7. Within the **pattern** text field enter `(.*)`
> 8. In the **Destination** text field enter `https://%{host}/$1`
> 9. Click **Add**

Comment: Hi Maximillian, the Verizon configuration page's rule does not contain a pattern text field but includes a source field. Also, the code dropdown does not have 308 code. Can you please explain what value should I enter in the source field and how can I set redirect code to 308

Comment: @Yash This may be about as much as I am able to personally help, given my lack of knowledge of this specific tool. On another note, is there a particular reason you specifically need a 308 status code, or would a 301 status code be close enough? Finally, here is another article that seems like it may be helpful: https://camerondwyer.com/2021/02/09/how-to-configure-url-redirects-using-verizon-premium-azure-cdn/